# How to disable "tomorrow only" on jquery date picker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hello im new with this jquery datepicker. I need to disabled tomorrow in jquery datepicker. Here is the following js script :

```
$(function() {
    $("#iDate").datepicker();
});
```

it just a normal jquery datepicker script without any option. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JjPrU/1391/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/JjPrU/1392/

```js
$(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var unavailableDate = (d.getDate() + 1) + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getFullYear();
  var unavailableDates = [];
  unavailableDates.push(unavailableDate);

  function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
  }

  $(function() {
    $("#iDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.17/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="iDate">
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Myrealname Welcome buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flowing code. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JjPrU/1393/)

```
var d = new Date();
var unavailableDate = [(d.getDate() + 1) + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getFullYear()];
function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDate) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#iDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

});
```